# Are there any reserved Fragment Tag names or formats?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using the Fragment compatibility support library and adding fragments like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content, frag, fragmentTag)
        .commit();
```

where `fragmentName` is used to identify a fragment, especially when getting the Fragment like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
```

My question is, are there any restrictions to what `fragmentTag` can be, or must it just be a String? Specifically, is it safe to use a url as a tag?

An authoritative source would be preferable in answering the question.

Comment: `findFragmentByTag` expects a String so you can't use other types of objects. If you use the url as a plain string you can use it for the tag(but not as a `Url` object if this is what you're asking).

Comment: No, I'm just asking if a `String` that happens to be a URL is fine, like the `String` "www.google.com" or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there are any restrictions on the `Strings` you use, because `fragmentTag` is just a unique identifier for your `Fragment`. It's totally up to you how to identify `Fragments`, you should select an option that best suits the needs of your application. Talking about URLs as `Fragment` identifiers - it's perfectly fine, but I don't recommend to use this approach for the sake of reusing those identifiers for other purposes. If you need a unique URL for a `Fragment`, you'll probably want to create a dedicated field in your `Fragment` extending class to differentiate it from your `Fragment`'s `fragmentTag` identifier. Hope this helps.